# The meaning of 'let out a dazed'

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

There is a small part of an story:

> 'Congratulations, Mark,' Alison said, 'You're the youngest Lottery winner we've ever had. Here's your cheque for $127,000.' I was so shocked, all I could do was **let out a dazed**, 'Thank you.'

I have looked up the word **dazed** but it's an adjective and it means confused. Therefore, It is quite unintelligible to me that what **a dazed** means.

Comment: *a dazed* modifies the utterance *Thank you'--the narrator spoke the words *Thank you* in a dazed manner. The comma which follows *a dazed* is 'mechanical' and should really be omitted.

Comment: Is **A dazed** a noun?

Comment: No -- the utterance 'Thank you' is treated as a noun, with the determiner *a* and the modifier *dazed*.

Comment: Try reading it as *all I could do was let out **a dazed 'Thank You'***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of "Thank you" (with which the sentence ends) as a single unit that functions as a noun. "Dazed" is an adjective used to describe this "noun".